# Icons got smaller in iOS 14, how to return them to normal size?

Tags: iphone, ios, icon

Throughout all history of iOS, the icons have had certain dimensions. Now, Apple for some reason decided to ruin this and made them smaller a little bit. They ruinded this, just as everything else, bit by bit. But, does anyone know how to return the icons to their original (pre - iOS 14)normal size, which has been throughout all older iOS-s?

[image: ios 14]

[image: ios 13]

To see this, open both of these images each in a new tab and click between them couple of times. You will see how the icons change size significantly.....I really would love to be able to go back to ios 13.....

Comment: I'm not aware of any and didn't notice anyone post that info during the iOS beta cycle.  It might be up to someone in the jailbreak community to figure it out.

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with jailbreak. Official ios14 has smaller icons.....so disappointing....the difference is barely noticable, but I can see it clearly....ver, very disappointing.

Comment: I guess they are only pushing the big screens....maybe on big screen iPhones (all newer iPhones, except iPhone SE 1) this change didn't occur.....I'm not sure since I only have iPhone SE 1.

Comment: I uploaded two screenshots. I have another iPhone SE which has ios 13 and my iPhone SE with ios 14 installed. I regret installing it.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with jailbreak.  My point was there is no way to change the icon size in iOS 14.  However, as usually happens, some smart jailbreaker will figure it out and post instructions.

Comment: ok. I am however surprised they did this in the first place, in the iOS. For me I think I will downgrade to ios13, since I am used to icons of THAT dimensions since many years ago.....I had iPhone 4 thru iPhone SE......and iOS 7 thru iOS 13 and am used to it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't see something blatantly different, but if you feel bad about it I suggest you tell Apple directly [through this link](http://apple.com/feedback/)

Besides that there is no other options in display to change the icon size it's either the "default" or "big".

Comment: I did a thorough research and it seems that yes, this is how APple wants the icons to be now......I don't like it. Doesn't mean you are not allowed to like it.... thanks anyway for the notice....

Answer (score 0):

The icon size has definitely changed in iOS 14, at least for models with 4.7" displays. They're 8 pixels smaller, from 122x122 to 114x114, and the space between them is narrower, leaving an excess of unused space to simply make the targets closer and smaller. I have checked this on a 7 and a 2020 SE, both show the same before and after. I'd like to think that there was either an internal, functional reason for this, or it was an accident that they'll correct, and not a designer's idea of something prettier. Here's the before and after shown in a group, (of some obsolete apps):
[image: Before and after iOS14]

[image]